# Why when im posting post to my facebook group page i see all the posts but members in my group don't see anything?

Tags: c#, facebook

This is how i post to the facebook:

```
private string PostFacebookWall(string accessToken, string message)
        {
            try
            {
                var objFacebookClient = new FacebookClient(accessToken);                
                var parameters = new Dictionary<string, object>();
                parameters["message"] = message;
                responsePost = objFacebookClient.Post("/" + GroupId + "/feed", parameters).ToString();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                responsePost = "Facebook Posting Error Message: " + ex.Message;
            }            
            return responsePost;
        }
```

I don't get any exceptions and i set my group in facebook the group i created to be Open. And that only Admin(me) can post.
I can see all the posts but all my members in the group can't see any posts my program sent.

What could be the problem ?

In my program i got access token then i made the access tokeb to be 60 days long.

EDIT**

Maybe the problem is when i did Get Access Token when i clicked on it in the Facebook Developers site ?

In the tab: User Data Permissions marked selected only: User_Friends and User_Status

In the tab: Friends Data Permissions nothing is selected.

In the tab: Extended Permissions what is marked selected: create_note photo_ipload publish_stream publish_actions status_update manage_pages publish_checkins share_item and video_upload.

Maybe i need to mark/selecte something more in one of the tabs ?

Comment: Now someone told me he see the posts from the program in c#. But my sisters and other say they don't see the posts. But if im adding a post manualy in the group everyone see it. So how come some members or someones see the posts from the program and some not ?

Comment: Maybe i need to publish my facebook app ? Or using app access token instead user access token ? Tried to google but didn't find anything clear about it yet.

Comment: Updated my question with more informations. Still no solution.

Comment: Is your app in development mode? (formerly called sandbox mode)  - if so, the posts made by teh app are only visible to admins of the app

Comment: lgy thanks working now.